# Error: React is Returning Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render some child elements using a reusable button component (class component). The button component accepts some props, and it also renders a Link conditionally.

Below is the code:

```
  render() {
    const {
      className,
      link,
      children,
      style,
      onClick,
      id,
      value,
      tabIndex,
      name
    } = this.props;

    if (link) {
  
      return (
        <Link className={className} onClick={onClick} to={link}>
          {children} 
        </Link>
      );
    }
    return (
      <button
        value={value}
        style={style}
        className={''}
        onClick={onClick}
        id={id}
        tabIndex={tabIndex}
        name={name}
      >
        {children}
      </button>
      
    );
  }
}

export default Button;
```

But React keeps returning an error saying :

````
 ```Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {__typename, symbol}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.```
````

Both the button and link components  render any children they contain.

Comment: what does the calling code look like? `<Button>...</Button>`

Comment: It sound like the value of the `children` prop is the problem. How are you using this component?

Comment: Yes, I am using it as a button component, and also to render a link conditionally. It is reusable

Comment: Can you share more of your code? How you are calling this component elsewhere?

Comment: The app is complex, I am using it in several use cases. One of the examples of where I am using it in a dropdown component.

Comment: I think console is saying I should use an array instead. But how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing an object, React can't render that because it's a complex object, basically it doesn't know what to do with that object. You can pass array or string or integer or other [primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive).

I have made an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-1oqpn4?file=/src/App.js).

Uncomment the line that passes `object` to the `Test` component and you see a similar error.

Comment: Nice, I couldn't think of what passing an object as children meant. Probably worth mentioning that they likely should just pass it as a regular property, e.g. `<Test value= {array} />`

Comment: This works but it seems i need to stringify it or something. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @EmmanuelEboh If you share what you are passing to your component and explain how you want it to be yes ofc

Comment: @Amir I'm simply rendering the "children" prop, which is basically any child component that is placed between it. You know children is a special kind of prop in React

Comment: @EmmanuelEboh I know this, I mean what is that `children`? Show me the code where you are doing something like `<CustomButton> ... </CustomButton>`. I want to know what is instead of these 3 dots.

Comment: @Amir Here is an example of using the button component in a dropdown list component. In order to map out a list of currency and the goods selected. It is an e-commerce app

Comment: <Button
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.stopPropagation();
              selectItem(currency);
            }}
            key={currency}
            className={classes.list__item}
          >
            <span>{currency.symbol}</span>
            {currency}
          </Button>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Comment: @EmmanuelEboh What is in `currency.symbol`?

Comment: @Amir It is a data from a GraphQL endpoint. I was querying the schema to get each currency symbol

Comment: @EmmanuelEboh You should convert it to an array or a primitive as I said, start with this `console.log(currency.symbol)` to see what's inside that and try to convert it.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

you must use your component this way: (asumming is named class Button ...)

```
<Button>Hello there!</Button>
```

Where "Hello there!" is the children prop.

Comment: Does this make the children prop dynamic?